# NameNotFoundException when application name contains a period

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb, jndi, jdeveloper

I have a simple EJB app that used to work about 6 months ago. I installed the latest JDeveloper (11.1.1.3.0) and I'm trying to get it to work again, when I ran into this problem.

Deployment fails on this line:

```
TeacherManager teacherManager = (TeacherManager)context.lookup("Uran_2.0-TeacherManager#hu.elte.pgy2.BACNAAI.UranEJB.TeacherManager");
```

With the message (emphasis by me):

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'Uran_2.0-TeacherManager#hu.elte.pgy2.BACNAAI.UranEJB.TeacherManager' **didn't find subcontext 'Uran_2'. Resolved ''** [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'Uran_2.0-TeacherManager#hu.elte.pgy2.BACNAAI.UranEJB.TeacherManager' didn't find subcontext 'Uran_2'. Resolved '']; **remaining name 'Uran_2/0-TeacherManager#hu/elte/pgy2/BACNAAI/UranEJB/TeacherManager**'

Apparently the application's name (Uran_2.0) somehow prompts JDeveloper (or JNDI? I'm not sure) to replace the `.` in the name with a `/`, which obviously causes the JNDI lookups to fail. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Stateless/Stateful EJB should explicitly specified the JNDI name :

`@Stateless(mappedName = ?)`

If this doesn't work, you can use `context.list("")` to browse the jndi tree in order to see what remote EJB are deployed.

Comment: Yep, it's there: `@Stateless(name = "TeacherManager", mappedName = "Uran_2.0-TeacherManager")`. JNDI still looks for `Uran_2/0-TeacherManager` though.

Comment: then lookup for "Uran_2\\.0-TeacherManager"

Comment: that gives: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'Uran_2.0-TeacherManager#hu.elte.pgy2.BACNAAI.UranEJB.TeacherManager' didn't find subcontext 'Uran_2.0-TeacherManager#hu'. Resolved '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'Uran_2.0-TeacherManager#hu.elte.pgy2.BACNAAI.UranEJB.TeacherManager' didn't find subcontext 'Uran_2.0-TeacherManager#hu'. Resolved '']; remaining name 'Uran_2/0-TeacherManager#hu/elte/pgy2/BACNAAI/UranEJB/TeacherManager'`. Slightly better, but not quite there yet.

Comment: the part "#hu/elte..." is probably optional (I don't know if you still include it like in the question). I have no idea what could fix it if you escape the dot. Here is a reference that mention the dot problem : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tnam_develop_naming.html.